# WordPress: why is my root page the Blog page despite this not being the case in Reading settings?

Tags: wordpress

So far I had no Blog page but I have a `front-page.php` template called when visiting the website root. Today I created a WP "Blog" page and set the settings as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Now, both the Blog page and the root/home page is run by index.php, whereas I want the home page to continue being run by `front-page.php`. How to fix that problem?

Comment: Have you checked for any issues with your front-page.php template? Are you able to create a new page through the WordPress admin and select your template front-page.php by its name in the page settings sidebar? Try to reproduce the following steps here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page, perhaps something might be missing along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress calls the template based upon how you have the "Front page displays" configured.  These settings and what is called confuses a lot of folks.  Bare with as I explain.

### Template Loader

WordPress sets the template to load in `wp-includes/template-loader.php`.  It's determined by the conditionals.  For front page versus home page, it's determined here:

```
elseif ( is_front_page()     && $template = get_front_page_template()     ) :
elseif ( is_home()           && $template = get_home_template()           ) :
```

Notice that if `is_front_page()` conditional is set, then the template to be loaded will be the `front-page.php`.  Else if `is_home()` is set, then the template is `home.php`.  Notice the order too, as `is_front_page()` is first.

### Front Page vs. Home Page

The front page can be:

- Posts Page
- *or* a static Front Page

Let's walk through the configuration settings to see which template is called.

#### Default Configuration

Out of the box, WordPress defaults to the "Front page displays" being set to "You latest posts."

[image: default front page configuration]

With this setting, WordPress does:

- Loads the `front-page.php` template file
- `is_home()` is set to `TRUE`
- `is_front_page()` is also set to `TRUE`.

#### Static Posts Page

[image: static Posts Page configured]

When you configure a static page as the "Posts Page" but nothing for the "static Front page," WordPress does the following:

- Loads the `home.php` template file
- `is_home()` is set to `TRUE`
- `is_front_page()` is to `FALSE`

This setting is telling WordPress that you want the Posts Page to be the root of your website.  The Posts Page will query all of the posts for you to display.

#### Both Statics Configured

[image: Front Page and Posts Page configured]

If you configure a static page for both the front and posts pages, then each template is called when you are on that page.

Website Root

When you are at the root of your website, `http://example.com/`, WordPress does:

- Loads the `front-page.php` template file
- `is_home()` is `FALSE`
- `is_front_page()` is `TRUE`

On Posts Page

When you are requesting to view the posts page, e.g. `http://example.com/blog`, WordPress does:

- Loads the `home.php` template file
- `is_home()` is `TRUE`
- `is_front_page()` is `FALSE`

### For You

If you are building a theme for resale, you will want to build your theme to comply with how WordPress determines which template to load.  Let the user configure what s/he wants through Settings > Reading.

If this site is for personal use, then you *could* write code to override WordPress and force it to load your `front-page.php` instead.  In doing so, keep in mind that if you ever change `Settings > Reading` configuration, it will not perform as expected.

#### Forcing the Front Page Template

Let's say you are not concerned about what is set in `Settings > Reading` and you want to force your website to use the `front-page.php` template.

In this edge case, you have to check the conditionals, load the `front-page.php`, and then return out of `home.php`.  You could do something like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Static Posts Page Template
 *
 * @package     YourTheme
 * @since       1.0.0
 * @author      yourname
 * @link        your link
 * @license     GNU-2.0+
 */

// Forcing this page to redirect to the front page template
if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) {
    require_once ( __DIR__ . '/front-page.php' );
    return;
}

// else do stuff
```

> Use this code with extreme caution, as it will be confusing to others.

#### Better Option

Move your code to a view file and then call it from within the appropriate template file and/or state.  Then your code is modular and available for reuse and readability without the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I've already faced this issue a few times for different reasons, yours might be different, so I'll list some thoughts here about what might be causing it and hopefully how to have it solved.

Selectively, you could try the following:

1. Make sure you have created a new page under WordPress admin and that you have selected your `front-page.php` template. Search for its name under the **Page Attributes** sidebar, see the example image bellow:

[image]

2. Go back to **Settings >> Reading** and re-check your static front page settings, make sure to select the page you created on Step 1 for which you've assigned the right template. Save changes.

[image]

---

For unknown reasons, some plugins or theme's settings might mess up with your permalinks. Although this is not directly related to the static front page settings, often times this triggers strange site wide behaviors. You could try to reset your permalinks just for the peace of mind.

3. Go to **Settings >> Permalinks** and pickup any option, Save changes. If you want to revert to your previous settings, pick it up and Save changes again. After Saving changes all your permalinks will be regenerated.

---

If you've followed Steps 1 and 2 or 3 (optional) and your `front-page.php` template is ok, you'd be able to see your template served as the front page of your website.

Otherwise, if it fails, you could try to debug for any critical erros on your website.

---

4. Make sure your `front-page.php` has no critical errors. For debug purposes you can enable the WP_DEBUG by placing `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` on your **wp-config.php**
5. After enabling the WP_DEBUG, visit your website to check for any erros.

---

Let us know if that helps. Good Luck!